# Get currency code based on symbol

Tags: php, currency, intl

I am currently working with an API where instead of floats or integers for currency I receive strings like these.

- $2.49
- £2.49
- €2.49
- etc.

The issue with that is that I need to store the value and currency separately but the currency needs to be stored as ISO Code, so for example EUR, USD or GBP instead of € and $.

Is there any way in PHP to get the currency code based on a currency symbol using the NumberFormatter or something like that?

Currently I just have a very long list of currency symbols and names which I use to do things like `string_contains('$2.49', '$')` to check for a certain currency.

Comment: There are be no general solution because multiple currencies use the same symbol. Eg. AUD, NZD, USD, … all use the dollar symbol.

Comment: @GauravDave — That does the opposite of what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could work with [NumberFormatter::parseCurrency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php):

```
<?php
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

echo "#1: ".$fmt->parseCurrency("$2.49", $curr)." in $curr<br>";
echo "#2: ".$fmt->parseCurrency("£2.49", $curr)." in $curr<br>";
echo "#3: ".$fmt->parseCurrency("€2.49", $curr)." in $curr<br>";
?>
```

Prints:

```
#1: 2.49 in USD
#2: 2.49 in GBP
#3: 2.49 in EUR
```

Note that Richard's comment about multiple currencies using the same symbol still applies but might be handled by specifying different locales for the `NumberFormatter`:

```
<?php
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_AU', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

echo "#1: ".$fmt->parseCurrency("$2.49", $curr)." in $curr<br>";
?>
```

Would e.g. change the first output to:

```
#1: 2.49 in AUD
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess that changing `en_US` to another country code may result in `$` being interpreted as a different currency according to locale.

Comment: Yep, confirmed.